# How can i understand if location services is using GPS or not to determine user's location in iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, currentlocation

Is there any way or method for getting the source of location if it is coming from GPS or from Wifi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Imho there is no way how to decide if signal comes from GPS or WIFI or whatever (this handles CoreLocation framework) - but you can still "decide" depending on current accuracy - the *horizontalAccuracy* property and *verticalAccuracy* property in *CLLocation* object.